# Is it possible to remove posts with specific tag from a category page in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, filtering

The situation is the following:

We have two separate shop pages: for sale & for rent. They both use the same categories and filters (filtering is made through https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-product-filter/8514038 plugin).

The problem is that when we search for a "Roadbike" category, both "for sale" & "for rent" results appear in the search page. We need only "for sale" to appear in the search. As I understand the filtering is made through category pages.

Maybe anyone knows a way how to work this out?

Comment: The proper WP way to do something like this would be to manipulate the query that fetches the posts using a hook such as `pre_get_posts`. Start with https://presscustomizr.com/snippet/three-techniques-to-alter-the-query-in-wordpress/ for a general explanation.

Comment: You should add action to `pre_get_posts` and check there is product cat you want or not. You can k it by `get_query_var`.